# Testing a Typescript React Component Giving Error on getByText

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library, ts-jest

I'm trying to add unit testing to an application written with Typescript and React. I have a very basic component just for the sake of simplicity.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

type TypeProps = { }
type TypeState = { }

class App extends React.Component<TypeProps, TypeState> {
    constructor(props:TypeProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { };
    }
    render() {
        return(<p>Literally Nothing</p>);
    }
}

function renderApp() {
    let AppElement = document.getElementById("app");
    if(AppElement) { ReactDOM.render(<App />, AppElement); }
}

renderApp();
export { renderApp }
```

Then installed what I believed to be everything required for the tests

```
npm install --save-dev jest ts-jest @types/jest
npm install --save-dev @testing-library/jest-dom @testing-library/react
```

With `jest.config.json` as

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom'
};
```

So this is all fine and I have a unit test of nothing

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

import { renderApp } from "./App";

test("Literally Nothing", function() {
    renderApp();
    expect(getByText("App")).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

But it is throwing the following error on `build` and `npm run test`

```
TS2304: Cannot find name 'getByText'.
```

Am I missing an install or configuration step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing getByText which is not imported anywhere.
I'd suggest you import screen

```
import { screen } from '@testing-library/react';
//....
renderApp();
const appText = screen.getByText("App");
expect(appText).toBeInTheDocument();
```

Also this will always assets false, because on your component there isn't any text with the value **"App"**, the onlye text that will render is **"Literally Nothing"**.

So like this will work:

```
const appText = screen.getByText("Literally Nothing");
expect(appText).toBeInTheDocument();
```

Comment: Dang it I'm an idiot, you're right this fixed it